# Singleton Object Created for each Request

Tags: java, spring, singleton, aspectj

I want to create a singleton object whose scope is basically only the request. This will be used to collect the errors and we need to send error whenever we send the response back.

Can anyone provide pointers toward this thing?
I am also using spring.

I tried using Spring container singleton object scope session or request but still my object is holding values from the earlier request

I am using this error object with AspectJ. Will that may cause problem on static binding?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure that singleton is what you want here - if two requests arrived concurrently they would share the singleton object, and their errors will get mixed up.

Is it possible to create an object to hold the errors and put that in to a ThreadLocal object. The scope of the object will be constrained by the request, and access to it in the ThreadLocal object is easily achieved from within your application without having to pass a refernce to the object around.

Comment: yes error get mixed up..i need to add error in this object using aspectj..then i need to get this object whenever i need to send request back..do you propose anyother alternative then sinlgeton object for this

Comment: In the code that handles the request, do something like ErrorHolder e = new ErrorHolder(); - take the ErrorHolder and put in it a ThreadLocal object ( http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/ThreadLocal.html ). Then, elsewhere in your application, when an error occurs, get the error handler from the ThreadLocal and update it. Finally, just before you reply to the client, get the ErrorHolder from the ThreadLocal again, and retrieve its values ready to be passed back to the client.

Answer (score 1):

how about

```
//sync this code
if(request.getAttribute("someKey") == null){
     // create object and set it
}
```

Comment: Perhaps a link to http://download.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/servlet/http/HttpServletRequest.html - setAttribute(String name, Object o)

Comment: sorry can you elaborate..how can i get this object on diffrent places of my application

Comment: Shouldn't be necessary that is what the http request scope on the spring container is for.

Comment: @Vish: You do have access to that variable in all places on the application for the same request. This of course assuming you do have access to the request in those places. If not, then there is probably something wrong in the layering of your application.

Answer (score 1):

If you set the Object life cycle in the Spring container to be per request then it should only exist for that HttpRequest.

Generally for direct injection containers like Spring when you set the object life cycle or object scope to be per request then it should create an new instance of the object for each http request that it recieves.

If it is not doing this then I would assume that it is more than likely something to do with your configuration.

Singleton is the defualt for the spring container when creating beans I think so you have to specifically set the object scope to per request.

Bean Scopes
http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/2.5.x/reference/beans.html

Answer (score -1):

You can use [ThreadLocal](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/lang/ThreadLocal.html).